# Can't move Screenlets when position is set to "Keep Above"

Tags: 12.04, compiz, screenlets, widgets

I've installed some screenlets and treat them as widgets. I did enable "widgets layer" plug-in in CCSM. But I got a little problem here, When I set position for the widget always on top of windows by checking "Keep Above" option, I can't move the widget anymore, but when set it to "Keep Below", no problem.

Is this a bug? If so, how could I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried right click on the screenlet--> windows ,and uncheck lock?

Comment: The "Lock" option is unchecked by default.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the gadget then in the popup menu go to Windows and click on keep below.

This could fix your problem! ;)

Comment: He wants To Keep above without problems a keep below is not a solution